# concatenate/join list of numbers to get a string

Tags: j

I want to join a list of integers in their order to obtain a final string, e.g.

```
a=.11 22 33 44
```

And I want to get `'11223344'`. And also, sometimes, I need to put a separator in between `'11 22 33 44'` like a space in this case. What is the simplest way?

Answer (score 6):

Use [format ":](http://www.jsoftware.com/docs/help701/dictionary/d602.htm) to covnert the list of numbers to a string:

```
":a
11 22 33 44
```

There are many ways to remove the space between them or to separate them with another string.

```
' ' -.~ ":a          NB. remove spaces (' ') from ":a
11223344

(":a) rplc ' ';', '  NB. replace spaces with ', ' (or anything else, even empty)
11, 22, 33, 44

,('-',~":)"0 a       NB. append '-' to every element of a; convert to string
11-22-33-44-
```

etc

Answer (score 5):

Another solution that can make it easier to deal with some situations.

Use the foreign `8!:0` to convert the numbers to boxed strings (this handles conversion of negative signs from `_` to `-`).

```
   8!:0 a
┌──┬──┬──┬──┐
│11│22│33│44│
└──┴──┴──┴──┘
```

Use the `joinstring` verb from the `strings` script/addon to join the boxed strings as required. For versions prior to J7 you will need to `require 'strings'` to ensure that the `joinstring` verb is available.

```
   ' ' joinstring 8!:0 a
11 22 33 44
   '' joinstring 8!:0 a
11223344
   '","' joinstring 8!:0 a
11","22","33","44
```